# IF statement doesn't work on ListView item android

Tags: java, android

`ListView` is generated from `JSON` with `boolean getExpired`.
if `getExpired()` is `TRUE`, then `textColor` should be changed.
but it set on list position even `if == FALSE`

Why 1st position is changed, if `getExpired` is `FALSE` on this item?

this is my getView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
        if (item.getExpired()) {
            vh.imageView.setColorFilter(filter);
            vh.profilePhoto.setColorFilter(filter);
            vh.expired.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vh.username.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#76808D"));
        }
    return vh.rootView;
}
```

Comment: what is item ?? post the full adapter code..

Comment: you are having problem with just the first position ??

Comment: no, for rest of list items, but totally random ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the ViewHolder pattern you will be getting recycled views which have already have their views set to a certain state. In short, when using ViewHolder also use an `else` condition to set your view states how you want them to be.